# Setting up MyEtherWallet on iOS device from Coinbase

Tags: security, myetherwallet, coinbase, ios

Can I securely set up and store a MyEthereumWallet on iOS only without an computer? I want to transfer ethers from Coinbase.

Comment: MyEthereumWallet  is just a mechanism to access your tokens online. What you want to say is not clear. If you have private of of the address then you can access your Funds from any device.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! There are some wallets for iOS or you can build your own on Geth library.